# LibGDX: parsing json with AIDE

Tags: java, android, json, libgdx, aide-ide

Learning LibGDX.
Using Android-IDE (AIDE).
Following this tutorial about using Skins to the letter:

https://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/12/18/LibGDX-Tutorial-9-Scene2D-Part-3-UI-Skins.aspx

Seeing this error in Logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 11270
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               Process: com.suchuu.gfstut9pt4, PID: 11269
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: data/uiskin.json
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:96)
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.<init>(Skin.java:73)
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.suchuu.gfstut9pt4.MyGdxGame.create(MyGdxGame.java:20)
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:236)
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1555)
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1270)
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: data/uiskin.json
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:662)
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:94)
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               ... 5 more
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException:
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.read(Skin.java:430)
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.read(Skin.java:424)
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:839)
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$1.readValue(Skin.java:418)
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:660)
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               ... 6 more
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.reflect.ReflectionException: Class not found: BitmapFont
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.reflect.ClassReflection.forName(ClassReflection.java:30)
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.read(Skin.java:428)
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               ... 10 more
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BitmapFont
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:378)
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.reflect.ClassReflection.forName(ClassReflection.java:28)
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               ... 11 more
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "BitmapFont" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.suchuu.gfstut9pt4-OcDpQootmuYDXjgvFj_dOA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.suchuu.gfstut9pt4-OcDpQootmuYDXjgvFj_dOA==/lib/arm, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/com.suchuu.gfstut9pt4-OcDpQootmuYDXjgvFj_dOA==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib]]
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
04-25 08:37:00.534 11269 11344 E   AndroidRuntime                               ... 15 more
```

I have written the same code as in the tutorial and followed every step precisely. I downloaded the UI assets and put them in assets/data, so I've no idea what I'm doing wrong.
Here's my code:

```
public class MyGdxGame implements ApplicationListener
{
   private SpriteBatch batch;
   private Skin skin;
   private Stage stage;

   @Override
   public void create()
   {
      batch = new SpriteBatch();
      skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/uiskin.json"));
      stage = new Stage();

      final TextButton button = new TextButton("Click me!", skin, "default");

      button.setWidth(200f);
      button.setHeight(20f);
    button.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - 100f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - 10f);

        button.addListener(new ClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            button.setText("You clicked the button!");
         }
      });

      stage.addActor(button);

      Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
   }

   @Override
   public void render()
   {        
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

      stage.draw();
   }

   @Override
   public void dispose()
   {
      batch.dispose();
   }

   @Override
   public void resize(int width, int height) {}

   @Override
   public void pause() {}

   @Override
   public void resume() {}
}
```

Comment: add libgdx tag.

Comment: Any advice related to my actual problem, though?

Comment: I think your issue lies in one of these files: uiskin.atlas, uiskin.json because your code looks good. One tip: You don't need to call `batch.begin()` and `batch.end()` around `stage.draw`, the stage has his own Batch and call these methods himself. Gamefromscratch is an old tutorial maybe you look for something newer like: https://www.gamedevelopment.blog/full-libgdx-game-tutorial-project-setup/ or https://expertise.jetruby.com/creating-android-game-from-scratch-with-libgdx-box2d-45c381d84268

Comment: I've had the same problem when downloading and trying to use those free skins like the glassy-ui files. And those files came straight from github, so not sure why this is happening, but thanks for the links, I'll check them out

Comment: Is the path to the uiskin.json correct? I've tried your code and it works fine. My assets folder structure is: [assets]->[skin]->[default]->[default.fnt, uiskin.atlas, uiskin.json, uiskin.png] and I load the skin with: `skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin/default/uiskin.json"));`

Comment: Also, look that your working directory is set to the assets folder.

Comment: Morchul: I tried to follow the tut as best I could, so I put the four files in assets > data, like so:           https://oi1161.photobucket.com/albums/q501/StudioGilliam/Screenshot_20190426-120942.jpg

Comment: In terms of the working directory - I've managed to successfully load .png and .jpg files from the assets folder in other works... So I imagine this project was setup correctly by the editor... But remember, I'm in AIDE (and I'm a total noob by this point) - I'm not sure how to change it in this app...

Comment: Oh, hey. I'd tried that gamedev.blog one before... Think I got stuck on that too, for similar reasons! I really need a laptop. >.<

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "BitmapFont" on path:

Comment: Just a tip: libGDX is great when you work on Java+Desktop, so you don't need to package/deploy (that takes time). On desktop (win/linux/osx) you make code changes and you can test them instantly. It's the best workflow for libGDX and gamedev. Try to develop most of the time on desktop, because package/deploy on android will slow you down a lot.

Comment: Yeah, I know... I dont have a laptop at the moment - its on my list of things to save for... My old one died a long time ago and the family desktop takes an hour to book up and may as well just be thrown out >.<